# Unreferenced Socket Objects during GC

Tags: java, sockets, collections, garbage-collection

I have a java.util.List object which holds connected sockets for pooling purposes. At some point I want to refresh this list. For this I set list size to 0. What happens to socket objects which were in the list before refresh. Will jvm properly close them during garbage collection ? or should I traverse the list and close each of them by myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects like `Socket` which hold OS resources will typically close these resources when garabage collected (for Sockets this is done in the finalizer of [AbstractPlainSocketImpl](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/net/AbstractPlainSocketImpl.html#finalize)).

But since it is not defined when garbage collection runs you should close such objects yourself to free these resources early. Else you run the risk of exhausting OS resources.

EDIT: also read the comment of Peter Lawrey who expressed it better than I can do why waiting for the GC to free OS resources is not a good idea.

Comment: To clarify, between clearing the list and closing the socket you could run out of file descriptors.  You also have the problem that the finalizer thread is single threaded and closing lots of IO resources can block it for long enough that anything else which need cleaning up has to be queued up and you can run out of memory waiting for this thread to do it's job.