# Java SSH Recursive Download causes memory leaks

Tags: java, recursion, memory-management, ssh, memory-leaks

I am using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) to provide an utility that backs up an entire server data for my company.

The application is developped using `Java 8` & `JavaFX 2`

My problem is that I believe that my recursive download is at fault because my program RAM usage is growing by the second and never seems to free up.

This is the order of the operations I perform :

1. Connexion to remote server : OK;
2. Opning SFT Channel -> `session.openChannel("sftp")` : OK
3. Retrieving local directory -> `sftpChannel.cd(MAIN_DIRECTORY)` : OK
4. Listing directory content -> `final Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> entries= sftpChannel.ls(".");`
5. Calling recursive method to :

   - `if (entry.getAttrs().isDir())`-> calling recursive method
   - else -> it's a file there are no more sub folder to go to ;
   - Process download

Now, where I think the memory leak occurs in the Download Part :

1. Starting download & retrieving the **inputstream**

   > final InputStream is = sftpChannel.get(remoteFilePath, new SftpProgressMonitor());

Where `SftpProgressMonitor()` is an interface to provide progress monitoring which I use for updating UI (progressbar). this interface **never references** internally the inputstream just to make that clear. But it's still an non-static anonymous class so it does hold a reference to the DownloadMethod scope.

2. While it's downloading, I create the file to save and open an **OutputStream** to write the downloaded content in it :

   > final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToSave));
3. This is where I write to file as the remote file gets downloaded :

Code:

```
int readCount;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    while ((readCount = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        bos.flush();
    }
```

And of course, once this is completed, I don't forget to close **both streams**:

```
is.close(); //the inputstream from sftChannel.get()
bos.close(); //the FileOutputStream
```

So as you can understand I recursively process these operations meaning :

1. List current directory content ;
2. Check first entry

   - if it's a directory, go inside, and do **1.**
   - it it's a file, download it
3. Check second entry
   etc.

Multiple tests show the exact same behaviour (and the content to download remain exactly the same during these tests). This means that my memory usage keeps growing and at the same pace.

### [UPDATE 1]

I tried a solution where I let JSch write to the `FileOutputStream` itself :

```
final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToSave));
sftpChannel.get(remoteFilePath, bos, new SftpProgressMonitor()
```

And in `SftpProgressMonitor.end()` I close -> `bos.close()`.

No changed at all.

I also tried listing all files, still recursively, adding their respective bytes length to a `private long totalBytesToDownload` and my program memory remained very stable : only 20Mb taken during the whole process (on the account that totalBytesToDownload kept increasing) which confirms that my downloading method is really at fault.

If I do close my streams, why the GC won't collect them ?

Comment: This will die on a symlink or a hardlink pointing up the hierarchy. Either use `rsync` or build a collection of things you copied already

Comment: Thank you @LevKuznetsov for pointing that out, but in my case I dismiss all symbolic links. What do you mean by `rscync` ?

Comment: `rsync` is a Linux utility meant to do exactly what you're doing. Google it. Even if you dismiss softlinks there's no way to tell if you're looking at a hardlink.

Comment: @LevKuznetsov the server is running Windows Server and I don't see such a method in Jsch :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unreferenced Socket Objects during GC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34851544/unreferenced-socket-objects-during-gc)